# Android Firebase - Error in get Value from a radiobutton

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a radio button to get size value in an eCommerce app 
I tried several codes but none work with me 
Any help with this one?
This is ProductDetailsActivity

```
private void addingToCartList(){

    String saveCurrentTime, saveCurrentDate;

    Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    saveCurrentTime = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());

    final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CartList");

    int selectId = msize.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectId);

    if (radioButton.getText() == null){
        return;
    }

    strsize = radioButton.getText().toString();

    final HashMap<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
    cartMap.put("pid", productID);
    cartMap.put("pname", productName.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("price",  productPrice.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
    cartMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
    cartMap.put("quantity", numberButton.getNumber());
    // cartMap.put("Shipping Time", Productshippingtime.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("discount", "");
    cartMap.put("size", msize);

    cartListRef.child("User view").child("Products").child(productID)
        .updateChildren(cartMap)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    cartListRef.child("Admin View")
                    //.child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone())
                        .child("Products").child(productID)
                        .updateChildren(cartMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {


                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    cartListRef.child("Admin view").child("Products").child(productID)
                                        .updateChildren(cartMap)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                Toast.makeText(ProductDetailsActivity.this, "Added to cart list.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProductDetailsActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

and this code in the same Activity to

```
private  void getProductDetails(String productID){


    DatabaseReference productsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

    productsRef.child(productID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Product product = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);

                productName.setText(product.getPname());
                productDescription.setText(product.getDescription());
                productPrice.setText(product.getPrice());
                //     productsize.setText(product.getSize());
                Productshippingtime.setText(product.getShippingtime());
                Picasso.get().load(product.getImage()).into(productImage);

                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                if(map.get("size")!=null){
                    strsize = map.get("size").toString();
                    switch (strsize){
                        case"small":
                            msize.check(R.id.rg_small);
                            break;
                        case"medium":
                            msize.check(R.id.rg_medium);
                            break;
                        case"large":
                            msize.check(R.id.rg_Large);
                            break;
                        case"xlarge":
                            msize.check(R.id.rg_xl);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I am getting this error

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getOverlay

in `addingToCartList();`

And this is class product

```
public class Product
{
    private String pname, description, price, image, category, pid, date, time;
    private String number;
    private String size, shipping, shippingtime;
    private String discount;



    public Product()
    {

    }


    public Product(String pname, String description, String price, String image, String category, String pid
            , String date, String time, String number, String size, String shipping, String shippingtime) {
        this.pname = pname;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
        this.category = category;
        this.pid = pid;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.number = number;
        this.size = size;
        this.shipping = shipping;
        this.shippingtime = shippingtime;

    }

    public Product(String discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public String getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(String discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }


    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getShipping() {
        return shipping;
    }

    public void setShipping(String shipping) {
        this.shipping = shipping;
    }

    public String getShippingtime() {
        return shippingtime;
    }

    public void setShippingtime(String shippingtime) {
        this.shippingtime = shippingtime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the content of your `Product` class.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: Please add the entire class including the fields.

Comment: sorry I was facing some issues posting the whole code

Comment: No, the project was working fine with this class until I added the radio buttons it won't allow me to add the order into the cart or save the data into firebase

Comment: Have you also added some other fields (like RadioButton) to the `Product` class?

Comment: Please give the full stack trace of the issue - com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getOverlay  is not an issue with your RadioButton